# Android.Views.InflateException: Error inflating class android.widget.Button with custom button selector

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm run into some problems on another project I'm working on, so I created a new project to see if I'm getting the same errors, which I am.

I've created a button inside **main.axml**, which I'm trying to style using **somestyle.xml**.

**somestyle.xml:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <!-- What to do when the button is NOT pressed -->
  <item android:state_pressed="false">

    <layer-list>
      <item android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp">

        <!-- Shape the button -->
        <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
        <solid android:color="#d13838"/>

      </item>


      <item android:bottom="2dp" android:left="2dp">
        <shape>
          <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#d13838" android:startColor="#d13838"/>
          <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#d13838"/>
          <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
          <padding android:bottom="0dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android="10dp"/>
        </shape>
      </item>
    </layer-list>

  </item>

</selector>
```

I'm getting a bunch of warnings:
[image]

However, the application builds but throws an exception on

> // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
>
> SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

in **MainActivity.cs**

```
Unhandled Exception:

Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.Button occurred
```

**Main.axml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:text="Btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/somestyle" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActiviy.cs:**

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace TestNamespaceBug
{
    [Activity(Label = "TestNamespaceBug", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
        }
    }
}
```

I can't figure out what's causing all the warnings + the exception. Greatly appreciate any suggestions on how to solve this.

Comment: I do think your "Shape the button" item misses a `<shape>`

Comment: Can't believe it was something so silly, thank you! Do you have any idea what's up with all the warnings?

Comment: I've never used Xamarin, so no, I don't :)